# Why do some characters get moving headshots in the Babylon 5 season 3 intro sequence?

Tags: babylon-5

After re-watching season 3 of Babylon 5 I noticed a bit of a discrepancy which I cannot account for.

Some cast members 'headshots' are stationary whereas others turn. There doesn't appear to be any connection with who turns their head and what sequence they are in, or even with what role they take in the show.

Is there a reason for some being turned one way or straight on or not?

Here is the intro for reference:-

Comment: Some of the actors were contracted to only be shot on their "good side"? :P

Comment: It's worth noting that all of the characters have some amount of movement; each of the ones that are not turning their heads either give a slight nod, a not-so-slight nod, or a bit of a swagger (Marcus) except for Sheridan who's as stone-like as he can be. So the point was probably movement of different kinds, rather than turning heads.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Nope, it doesn't mean a thing.  Presumably it was done simply for style.

Showrunner J. Michael Straczynski answered this question on usenet. The following is referenced from [The Lurker's Guide](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/guide/045.html):

> **Q:** *Any significance to some characters heads turning in the opening credits?*
>
> **JMS :** *No, I don't think even I could ever manage to be that obscure.*